# Gatling HttpProtocolBuilder sign request with auth header for each request

Tags: java, load-testing, gatling

As aws auth signatures are expiring in 5 mins, i would like to refresh auth headers for long running tests, either for every less than 5 mins or for each request, i tried http.sign method, but it does not get invoked for some reason

here is how the code looks

```
HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = LoadTestHelper.getHttpProtocolBuilder(ENDPOINT);
String payload = "JSON payload";
ScenarioBuilder users = scenario("Users").exec(http("initiation").post(ENDPOINT).headers(getAuthHeaders()).body(StringBody(payload)).check(status().is(200)));
users.injectOpen(rampUsersPerSec(1).to(LOAD_USERS).during(Duration.ofSeconds(LOAD_DURATION)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sign method works fine,i was applying sign with HttpProtocolBuilder, but it supposed to be http in ScenariooBuilder, the syntax is something like this

```
  ScenarioBuilder users = scenario("Users").exec(http("initiation").post(ENDPOINT).sign(request -> {
        Map<String, String> headers = LoadTestHelper.getAuthHeaders();

        for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : headers.entrySet())
        {
            request.getHeaders().add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }).body(StringBody(payload)).check(status().is(200)));
```